# fetch values from database according to week

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database containing a table with multiple fields, with one of the fields as a DateTime field. now what I want to do is fetch some rows from the database according to a week selection, so I want to select them according to a week selected by the user from a dropdownlist. ( week 1, week 2...) the records will be later displayed in a chart.
The date in the database is diplayed as follow( exp:07-JAN-13) in an access database.
So does anybody have any idea what the sql query should be like? and how can do such selection by week?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format a date to a week number:

```
 Format(Date(),"ww")
```

Which means you can query on that format.

```
 SELECT ADateTime FROM ATable
 WHERE Format(ADateTime,"ww")=2
```

Reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/format-property-date-time-data-type-HA001232739.aspx

Comment: one more question remou! do you know how I can browse my table to see what weeks I have? so that I could put the weeks numbers in the dropdownlist ..

Comment: As in `SELECT DISTINCT Format(ADateTime,"ww") FROM ATable` ?